# Remove item from list which doesnt exist in other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table `Data` with two fields `Id` and `Value`

I have Created an entity model of `Data` table

Now after some operations i have two lists :

- List of Data from database as `List<Data> dbData = dbcontext.Datas.ToList();`
- List of Data i generated throw some other mean which is `myData`

Both `dbData` and `myData` are of same type which is `List<Data>`

Now i want to delete the `Data` items from `dbData` where the Ids of `dbData` doesn't exist in `myData`.

example:
let say `dbData` and `myData` have values as :

```
dbData => Id = 1 , Value = "value1"
          Id = 2 , Value = "value2"
          Id = 3 , Value = "value3"

myData => Id = 1 , Value = "value1"
          Id = 2 , Value = "value2"
```

i want to delete the 3rd row as it does not present in myData but is still in database list.

I was trying to do it like

```
 foreach(var d in dbData)
                {
                    foreach(var m in myData)
                    {
                        if(d.Id != m.Id)
                        {
                            db.Datas.Remove(d);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

i don't think is the correct way to do this

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: @StefanoCavion i just did please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to load all the data into memory doing `List<Data> dbData = dbcontext.Datas.ToList();`.

You could load only the entities to delete:

```
var myDataIds = myData.Select(a => a.Id).ToList();
var dataToDelete = db.Datas.Where(a => myDataIds.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
db.Datas.RemoveRange(dataToDelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It's still not ideal that you need to load the data just to delete it. In this case though, you would only load 1 entity, instead of 3.

Are you familiar with Dapper? It's a micro ORM that would allow you to do this just by writing a sql query. In the projects that I work, we use both EntityFramework and Dapper, and choose based on our needs.

Comment: There is an error at `Contains(a.Id)`. cannot convert int to Data

Comment: Did you add `var myDataIds = myData.Select(a => new Data() { Id = a.Id}).ToList();`? That should be of type `List<int>`. The contains should be done on `myDataIds`, not on `db.Datas`.

Comment: Yes i have added it and It is of type List<Data> because we are selecting new Data type list?

Comment: Oh, my bad, that was from a previous version of the answer. I updated it, it should be ok now. Sorry for that!

Comment: Thanks for taking out some of your precious time!

Answer (score 0):

Try `dbData.RemoveAll (_ => !myData.Exists(t => t.Id == _.Id));`
dbData contains just values 1 and 2

Comment: Please don't ever use `_` as anything other then a discard. It might work in this case but can lead to compilation errors in other cases. And in general it makes it more confusing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards